# Pandas Join / Lookup for NaN Values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to efficiently replace NaN values in a dataset with values from another dataset.
Suppose I have a dataframe df and a lookupDF as such:

```
df:
Key Name ExtraInfo
0  'A'   'a'
1  'B'   'b'
2  ''    'c'

lookupDF:
Key  Name
0    'A'
1    'B'
2    'C'
3    'D'
```

I'd like to replace the empty Name in df with what gets found in the lookup table.
In pseudocode:

```
FOR row IN df:
  IF Name is empty:
    Name = lookupDF[key]
```

Is there any good way to do this? I've tried a left merge on Name, though that adds extra rows to the original dataframe (lookupDF is larger than df!)

Comment: you want [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

update `NaN` values with df2 values.

```
import numpy as np
df1.Name =df1.Name.replace("''",np.NaN)
df1 = df1.fillna(df2)
# df1 = df1.set_index('Key').fillna(df2.set_index('Key')).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `pd.Series.map`:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace('',np.nan).fillna(df['Key'].map(lookupDF.set_index('Key')['Name']))
```

Output:

```
   Key Name ExtraInfo
0    0    A         a
1    1    B         b
2    2    C         c
```